# ¿Por que no se ve checkbox en un listview añadiendolo con el metodo "addView"?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Tengo un adaptador perzonalizado para mi list view y la funcion getview es esta:

```
`public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interfaz_elementos_listview_detalles, null);
            vista_actual=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_dinamica);
            actual_chek= (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_procesar);
            vista_actual.removeView(actual_chek);
            vista_actual.addView(actual_chek);
        return convertView;
       }`
```

Cuando aplico el método "`vista_actual.removeView(actual_check)`" remueve satisfactoriamente el `checkbox`, pero al utilizar la sentencia "`vista_actual.addView(actual_chek);`" no pasa nada. Sin embargo si ejecuto una vez mas la sentencia "`vista_actual.addView(actual_chek);`" la `app` se detiene diciendo que el elemento ya existe.¿Alguna alma caritativa que me ayude?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que pasa pero podrias tratar varias cosas. Debuggear y ver los childs de tu lista, ver el tamaño de la lista después de remover el checkbox, invalidar la lista para detonar un redraw, arregar layouParams al checkbox después de removerlo

Comment: Ya lo resolví. Era un problema de "ambiguedad" en el acomodo del layout. Tenia un LinearLayout principal con varios elementos dentro de el, entre esos elementos estaba el checkbox. Yo supongo que al añadir el view (checkbox) android tuvo un "problema de acomodo".Lo que hice fue poner mi view(checkbox) en un layout(padre) nuevo para que este le "guardara su espacio" en el layout en tiempo de ejecucion.